# Reassigning variable, delete called twice (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

My programming background is the Java world, but I've just started learning C++. I've stumbled across this rather trivial and probably pretty noobish problem that somehow puzzles me as a Java programmer:

I have a class with an array which is initialized via new in the constructor and deleted in the destructor. Now when I create an object of this class and assign another object of this class to the same variable (at least that is what I think it is), the delete[] method in the destructor seems to be called twice when the variables leave the scope (in this case the main() function) (the debugger gives me an _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID assertion failed warning).

Why is that? Why isn't the deconstructor called before I assign a new object to f? How could I explicitely delete Foo(1)? What exactly happens here?

```
class Foo{
    private:
        int *field;

    public:

    Foo(int size){
       field = new int[size];
    }

   ~Foo(){
       delete[] field;
    }
};


int main(){
    Foo f = Foo(1);
    f = Foo(2);
}
```

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three........................................................................................ More relevant: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C++.pdf

Comment: You could save yourself all the trouble by using an `std::vector<int>` instead of the dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is something in the C++ world called the [Rule Of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

A class will automatically generate a **destructor**, **copy constructor**, and **assignment operator** for you.

If you have to *manually define* one of those functions, you probably have to define all three of them.

In your case, you should define the two copy functions, so that a copy of `Foo` gets its own copy of `field`.  Add these two functions:

```
class Foo{

    Foo( const Foo &f ) {
        size = f.size;
        field = new int[size]; 
        std::copy( f.field, f.field + size, field );
    }

   Foo& operator=( const Foo &f ) {
       // Leverage the logic that was already written in the copy constructor
       Foo tmp(f);
       std::swap( *this, temp );
       return *this;
   }
};
```

*Note that I'm assuming that you've stored `size` in the `Foo` object.  You would probably need to store that information anyway in a real-life application*

Comment: @Treecj Lucian Grigore makes good points too.  If you're coming from Java, it will be *much breezier* if you avoid pointer management wherever you can, such as with his `vector` suggestion.  That would put you on the "zero" side of the RoT.

Comment: Thx again. There might be a little error in your definition of the copy constructor however: The old field does not exist (does it?) in the context of this constructor, hence cannot be deleted...? At least when I tried implementing it that way I got a runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

You're not following the rule of three, which is bad. Because the default copy constructor does a shallow copy, all your automatic variables (`f` and the temporaries) have the `field` member pointing to the same `int`, which is destroyed multiple times when the destructor is called.

Implement a proper copy constructor, or use C++ idioms and avoid manual management alltogether - i.e. use a `std::vector` instead.